# Does a perfectly matched impedance matching stub instead reflect if the ports are matched?

Tags: impedance-matching

Let's say I have some 2-port circuit with an impedance of 50ohms and 75ohms for port1 and port 2, respectively.

If I design some open-circuit single-stub impedance matching circuit, which results in the S-parameter S11 being 0dB, if I instead use the circuit betweeen two ports of 50ohms, what would the behavior of the S11 be? Would the majority of the signal be reflected back to port 1 since the matching stub is now contributing in a destructive manner?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use the circuit between two ports of 50 ohms"? A diagram might make it clear what you mean here. Are you modifying your 2-port network to include this stub? If so, where in the network? Or are you placing the stub in front of port 1? Or after port 2?

Comment: @ThePhoton Basically just keep the circuit exactly the same after getting the stub to match impedance as desired, just change the impedance of port 2 to 50 ohms

Comment: Are you changing the actual design of the network, or just re-analyzing it in a 50-ohm system instead of a 75-ohm system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining (by analysis or measurement) \$S_{11}\$, port 2 is assumed to be terminated with its characteristic impedance, so that there will be no wave entering at port 2.

Therefore if you design a matching circuit (a stub or any other kind) for port 1, its performance as a matching circuit only depends on \$S_{11}(f)\$, not on \$S_{22}\$ or what the characteristic impedance of port 2 is. (Assuming you can change the behavior of port 2 without altering \$S_{11}\$.

> If I design some open-circuit single-stub impedance matching circuit, which results in the S-parameter S11 being 0dB ...

If the magnitude of \$S_{11}\$ is 0 dB, it means you have complete reflection at port 1. You have made a complete mismatch rather than a good match. No signal will enter the network, and (if it's a passive network) there will be no output at port 2 (\$S_{21} = 0\$).